# Obfuscating and replacing the Alphabets with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, obfuscation

I'm looking for a way to obfuscate the alphabet. What I specifically mean by "obfuscating the alphabet" is replacing the input letters with the second array letters. For example, I want to replace all letters in this array (the second array): `['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];` with this array:

`["z", "y", "x", "w", "v", "u", "t", "s", "r", "q", "p", "o", "n", "m", "l", "k", "j", "i", "h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]` so like if my input letter is "a b c", the output letter would be " z y x".

Comment: research: *substitution cipher in javascript*

Comment: Hey @Kadal, I added a solution as an answer but since you look to have found your own, you could answer this question yourself too. Answering your own question, when you find a solution, helps others who run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already found an answer yourself. Here's an option for anyone else looking for a basic substitution cypher:

```js
const substitutionCypher = (input) => {
  // input should be a string; do your own validation
  
  const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
  const cypherbet = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA'.split('');
  
  const resultArray = input.split('').map(char => {
    return (alphabet.includes(char)) ? cypherbet[alphabet.indexOf(char)] : char;
  });
  
  return resultArray.join('');
}

// Example usage:
console.log(substitutionCypher('hello !@#5638 WORLD! 83929$$'));
```